# SQL Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement in MS Access VBA subroutine

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, syntax-error

I am working on a subroutine in Microsoft Access VBA.  The intended purpose of my program is to create a new table called `newTableName` and then perform a join on the two tables `tableName1` and `tableName2`.  The result of this join should be stored in `newTableName`.  From my research online, I am led to believe that I cannot create an empty table to store the joined data in.  So, I have attempted to duplicate `tablenName2` and store its data in `newTableName` until the join is performed.

However, I get the following error when I run my program:

> Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
>
> Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.

From this line:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strNewTableQuery
```

Which was tested with user input resulting in this query:

```
CREATE TABLE [UNIX_lob] AS SELECT * FROM UNIX
```

Here is my code:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub JoinWithIIMMModule()

    Dim sqlNewTableQuery    As String
    Dim sqlJoinQuery        As String
    Dim tableName1          As String
    Dim tableName2          As String
    Dim newTableName        As String
    Dim commonField         As String
    
    ' Set the common field used to join the two tables '
    commonField = "[code]"
    
    ' Set the tableName1 to be used in the join. '
    tableName1 = "IIMM"
    
    ' Acquire name of table to be joined with table1 from the user'
    tableName2 = InputBox("Enter name of the table which you would like to join with " + tableName1 + ":", _
             "Table to split", "UNIX")
             
    ' Set the name of the new table where the joins will be stored.'
    newTableName = "[" + tableName2 + "_lob]"
             
    ' Create newTableName, which is a duplicate of the tableName2 table.'
    ' This is where the joined data will reside.'
    sqlNewTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + newTableName + " AS SELECT * FROM " + tableName2
    Debug.Print sqlNewTableQuery
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute sqlNewTableQuery
    
    ' Join tableName1 and tableName2 on commonField, and store the joined data in newTableName'
    sqlJoinQuery = "SELECT " + tableName1 + ".*, " + tableName2 + ".*" & _
                 "INTO " + newTableName & _
                 "FROM " + tableName1 & _
                 "INNER JOIN " + tableName2 & _
                 "ON " + tableName1 + "." + commonField + " = " + tableName2 + "." + commonField + ";"
    Debug.Print sqlJoinQuery
    CurrentDb.Execute sqlJoinQuery

End Sub
```

Does anybody know what might be causing this error?

Comment: Your syntax for creating a new table "CREATE TABLE [UNIX_lob] AS SELECT * FROM UNIX" is not going to work. The correct syntax for this would be "select * into UNIX_lob from UNIX". You can extend this style of syntax with join if you want/need to.

Comment: @SeanLange Does `SELECT INTO` work in Ms-Access?  I didn't think that it did?

Comment: @RBarryYoung as I understand it they are using Access as the front end with SQL Server as the database. If that is correct then it should work. But I think you are correct that SELECT INTO is a sql-server "local dialect" as JC would say. :D

Comment: Your title says "Access", but your tags say *both* Sql-Server and Access.  Which is it?  In either event, Sean is right that `CREATE TABLE [UNIX_lob] AS SELECT * FROM UNIX` is Oracle-specific syntax and will not work on Microsoft products such as either Access nor SqlServer.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Thanks for pointing that out.  I will update OP to remove sql-server

Comment: @SeanLange: That solved the issue, however since I have `INTO " + newTableName ` later on, then it tries to recreate an already existing table.  In that case, I will only create the table in the join as you suggested.  I uncovered another bug in my code since the `Resultant table not allowed to have more than one AutoNumber field`.  However, the syntax error in the question has been solved.

Comment: So simply change the second part to be a straight forward insert. That should get around the problem.